# Stop using the string when there is a special character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file file1.txt. I have already performed preprocessing (cleaning) on it. Operations like replace("-","") etc. Now I want to perform few more operations on the clean text string. How can I check if the string is cleaned or not i.e without any special characters like @!#$%^ etc.? If not cleaned it should print invalid entry? Can I do it without using re?

```
def process():
 with open("file1.txt",'r') as a:
            text = a.read #toconvert into string
            for ch in ['_','-']:
                 text = text.replace(ch,"")
            return text
process()
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and provide a complete example. Without knowing more about your problem, it's hard to suggest a solution. With that said, regex is probably your best bet and you can easily do this with `re.search(r"[yourspecialchars]", word)`

Comment: Hi @SyntaxVoid, can we do it without using re ?

Comment: You could write  "if" statement for every single latin alphabet value or involve usage of set of ord()/chr() functions through specific ranges of accepted values. Ideally, the regex is probably among fastest and simplest implementations.

Comment: Using two nested for-loops: sure. Have one loop over your text file word (one char at a time) and another loop over your special characters. Then check if they're the same. There are many ways to do this. Try one yourself and feel free to post it here if you have errors, but please post the code you tried next time. SO is not a code-writing service

Comment: if the real problem is behind "i don't know what special character is possible" (i'm guessing now), then invert the condition for check - through valid values
`!re.search(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]", character)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using regex, you can do this:

```
special_char = '@!#$%^' # maybe string.punctuation?
text ='I love pizza and chips@'

print("Invalid") if any(c in special_char for c in text) else print("Valid")
```

---

To answer your second question, you should write in your case:

```
ch = '@#$%^&*' 

with open(cleanfile, 'r') as s: 
    s = s.readlines()
    if any(c in ch for c in s):
        print('Invalid')
    else:
        li = s.split()
```

Comment: Why down vote? Please explain, I seem to have requested the request

Comment: Hey @Massifox, it is giving an error of "can't assign to conditional statement" Thanks

Comment: which python version do you use?

Comment: Python 3.7 Pycharm

Comment: This code works ... are you running exactly that? If you are running other code try posting it I watch

Comment: I wrote ```with open(cleanfile, 'r') as s: s = s.readlines()   ch = '@#$%^&*' print("Invalid") if any(c in ch for c in s) else li = s.split()``` @Massifox

Comment: write the if-statement on two lines: `if any(c in ch for c in s):
    print('Invalid')
else:
    li = s.split()`